# Height of text in minipage - columns not parallel

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I’m using `minipage` for the design of my thesis’ titlepage. I have two columns and the problem I see there is, the texts in both are not at the same height.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    By:\\
    Student Number:\\[3ex]
    Supervisor:\\
    Supervisor:\\[3ex]
    Place, \today
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth} 
    Christian Lastname\\
    12345678\\[3ex]
    Name\\
    Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong name\\[3ex]
    $~~$
\end{minipage}
```

Do you have an idea to put all lines on an equal level?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Use `\begin{minipage}[t]` for both of them!

Comment: or simpler use `\begin{tabular}{ll}by:&Christian Lastname\\...` so alignment is automatic.

Comment: @ChristianFu `[h]`? Where do you put this? Does not work for `minipage`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the top align parameter `[t]` of the `minipage` environment here.

```
% arara: lualatex
% you may use pdflatex, just remove the package I've loaded    

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} % just for demo

\begin{document}
\noindent % this was missing
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    By:\\
    Student Number:\\[\baselineskip]
    Supervisor:\\
    Supervisor:\\[\baselineskip]
    Place, \today
\end{minipage}% <= this percent sign was missing
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth} 
    Christian Lastname\\
    1234578\\[\baselineskip]
    Name\\
    Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong name\\[\baselineskip]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]